# How can I loop through every div that starts with a specific string using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through every div that start with the word "Held" and check remove it if it does not exists into another object.

Here is what I have done

```
$.each($("div[id^='Held']"), function(key, val){
    var divName = $(this).attr('id');
    var uniqueId = divName.replace('Held', '');

    if ($.inArray(uniqueId, data.onHold) === -1){

        $('#' + ivName).remove();
    }
});
```

I also tried this syntax

```
$("div[id^='Held']").each(function(key, val){

    var divName = $(this).attr('id');
    var uniqueId = divName.replace('Held', '');

    if ($.inArray(uniqueId, data.onHold) === -1){

        $('#' + ivName).remove();
    }
});
```

but it is not removing the div as expected

Comment: Is the typo `ivName` in the real code or just a copying error? Why don't you just use `$(this).remove()`?

Comment: You could use the parameter "key"

Comment: You should use the second syntax. `$.each` is for arrays and objects, `$(selector).each()` is for jQuery collections.

Comment: check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/ahmon_abilar/L8n28gys/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use a selector when you already have the element you want to remove in a variable.

```
$("div[id^='Held']").each(function(){

    var divName = this.id;
    var uniqueId = divName.replace('Held', '');

    if ($.inArray(uniqueId, data.onHold) === -1){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

You could also use `.filter`:

```
$("div[id^='Held']").filter(function() {
    var uniqueId = this.id.replace('Held', '');
    return $.inArray(uniqueId, data.onHold) === -1;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was is when searching in an item is in array. My Array had an object in each one of its value.

Here is what I have done to correct this issue

```
//This will search for all div with Id starts with "Held" and it will loop through them
$("div[id^='Held']").each(function(){

    var divName = this.id;
    var uniqueId = divName.replace('Held', '');

    if ( isItemExists(uniqueId, data.onHold, 'interactionId') ){
        this.remove();
    }
});

// This function will find a value inside a
function isItemExists(needle, haystack, elementKey){
    return $.grep(haystack, function(item){
      return item.elementKey== needle;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using the `key` parameter:

```
var elms = $("div[id^='Held']");

elms.each(function(key, val){

    var divName = $(this).attr('id');
    var uniqueId = divName.replace('Held', '');

    if ($.inArray(uniqueId, data.onHold) === -1){

        elms.eq(key).remove();
    }
});
```